# How to link statically built 3rd party OpenCV libraries with CMake?

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, cmake, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make an application that runs on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B that uses OpenCV. I'm opting to build any library dependencies so that the application is self-contained. I'm also opting to make them static libraries rather than shared ones so I don't have to deal with runtime dependencies.

When trying to build OpenCV from the source, all of the 3rd-party libraries compile fine, but for some reason modules such as `opencv_waldboost_detector`, `opencv_annotation`, `opencv_visualisation`, and `opencv_interactive-calibration` give linking errors:

```
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jdmarker.c.o): In function `get_dht':
jdmarker.c:(.text.get_dht+0x3a4): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jdmarker.c.o): In function `read_markers':
jdmarker.c:(.text.read_markers+0xf0c): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_quant_table'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibtiff.a(tif_jpeg.c.o): In function `TIFFjpeg_abort':
tif_jpeg.c:(.text.TIFFjpeg_abort+0x24): undefined reference to `jpeg_abort'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibtiff.a(tif_jpeg.c.o): In function `TIFFjpeg_error_exit':
tif_jpeg.c:(.text.TIFFjpeg_error_exit+0x40): undefined reference to `jpeg_abort'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibtiff.a(tif_jpeg.c.o): In function `TIFFjpeg_destroy':
tif_jpeg.c:(.text.TIFFjpeg_destroy+0x24): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibtiff.a(tif_jpeg.c.o): In function `TIFFjpeg_progress_monitor':
tif_jpeg.c:(.text.TIFFjpeg_progress_monitor+0x4c): undefined reference to `jpeg_abort'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jcapimin.c.o): In function `jpeg_destroy_compress':
jcapimin.c:(.text.jpeg_destroy_compress+0x0): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jcapimin.c.o): In function `jpeg_finish_compress':
jcapimin.c:(.text.jpeg_finish_compress+0x124): undefined reference to `jpeg_abort'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jcparam.c.o): In function `jpeg_add_quant_table':
jcparam.c:(.text.jpeg_add_quant_table+0x120): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_quant_table'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jcparam.c.o): In function `jpeg_set_defaults':
jcparam.c:(.text.jpeg_set_defaults+0x280): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
jcparam.c:(.text.jpeg_set_defaults+0x344): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_quant_table'
jcparam.c:(.text.jpeg_set_defaults+0x354): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_quant_table'
jcparam.c:(.text.jpeg_set_defaults+0x364): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
jcparam.c:(.text.jpeg_set_defaults+0x410): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
jcparam.c:(.text.jpeg_set_defaults+0x4b8): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jcphuff.c.o): In function `finish_pass_gather_phuff':
jcphuff.c:(.text.finish_pass_gather_phuff+0x278): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
jcphuff.c:(.text.finish_pass_gather_phuff+0x28c): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jcphuff.c.o):jcphuff.c:(.text.finish_pass_gather_phuff+0x2a0): more undefined references to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table' follow
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jdapimin.c.o): In function `jpeg_destroy_decompress':
jdapimin.c:(.text.jpeg_destroy_decompress+0x0): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jdapimin.c.o): In function `jpeg_read_header':
jdapimin.c:(.text.jpeg_read_header+0xd0): undefined reference to `jpeg_abort'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jdapimin.c.o): In function `jpeg_finish_decompress':
jdapimin.c:(.text.jpeg_finish_decompress+0x88): undefined reference to `jpeg_abort'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jdmaster.c.o): In function `jinit_master_decompress':
jdmaster.c:(.text.jinit_master_decompress+0x354): undefined reference to `jinit_inverse_dct'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jerror.c.o): In function `error_exit':
jerror.c:(.text.error_exit+0x18): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jchuff.c.o): In function `finish_pass_gather':
jchuff.c:(.text.finish_pass_gather+0x108): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
jchuff.c:(.text.finish_pass_gather+0x12c): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jdhuff.c.o): In function `jinit_huff_decoder':
jdhuff.c:(.text.jinit_huff_decoder+0xb0): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
jdhuff.c:(.text.jinit_huff_decoder+0x154): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
jdhuff.c:(.text.jinit_huff_decoder+0x200): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg-turbo.a(jdhuff.c.o):jdhuff.c:(.text.jinit_huff_decoder+0x2a8): more undefined references to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table' follow
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibwebp.a(frame_dec.c.o): In function `ReconstructRow':
frame_dec.c:(.text.ReconstructRow+0x6c4): undefined reference to `VP8PredChroma8'
frame_dec.c:(.text.ReconstructRow+0x6c8): undefined reference to `VP8PredLuma16'
frame_dec.c:(.text.ReconstructRow+0x6cc): undefined reference to `VP8TransformDC'
frame_dec.c:(.text.ReconstructRow+0x6d0): undefined reference to `VP8TransformAC3'
frame_dec.c:(.text.ReconstructRow+0x6d4): undefined reference to `VP8TransformUV'
frame_dec.c:(.text.ReconstructRow+0x6d8): undefined reference to `VP8TransformDCUV'
frame_dec.c:(.text.ReconstructRow+0x6dc): undefined reference to `VP8Transform'
frame_dec.c:(.text.ReconstructRow+0x6e0): undefined reference to `VP8PredLuma4'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibwebp.a(frame_dec.c.o): In function `FinishRow':
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x850): undefined reference to `VP8DitherCombine8x8'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x854): undefined reference to `VP8HFilter16'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x858): undefined reference to `VP8HFilter8'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x85c): undefined reference to `VP8VFilter16'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x860): undefined reference to `VP8VFilter8'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x864): undefined reference to `VP8VFilter16i'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x868): undefined reference to `VP8VFilter8i'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x86c): undefined reference to `VP8SimpleHFilter16'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x870): undefined reference to `VP8SimpleVFilter16'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x874): undefined reference to `VP8SimpleVFilter16i'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x878): undefined reference to `VP8HFilter16i'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x87c): undefined reference to `VP8HFilter8i'
frame_dec.c:(.text.FinishRow+0x884): undefined reference to `VP8SimpleHFilter16i'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibwebp.a(frame_dec.c.o): In function `VP8InitFrame':
frame_dec.c:(.text.VP8InitFrame+0x32c): undefined reference to `VP8DspInit'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibwebp.a(vp8_dec.c.o): In function `VP8DecodeMB':
vp8_dec.c:(.text.VP8DecodeMB+0x558): undefined reference to `VP8TransformWHT'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibwebp.a(enc.c.o): In function `VP8EncDspInit':
enc.c:(.text.VP8EncDspInit+0x40): undefined reference to `VP8DspInit'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibwebp.a(quant_enc.c.o): In function `ReconstructIntra16':
quant_enc.c:(.text.ReconstructIntra16+0x534): undefined reference to `VP8TransformWHT'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibwebp.a(filter_enc.c.o): In function `VP8StoreFilterStats':
filter_enc.c:(.text.VP8StoreFilterStats+0x284): undefined reference to `VP8HFilter16i'
filter_enc.c:(.text.VP8StoreFilterStats+0x288): undefined reference to `VP8HFilter8i'
filter_enc.c:(.text.VP8StoreFilterStats+0x28c): undefined reference to `VP8VFilter16i'
filter_enc.c:(.text.VP8StoreFilterStats+0x290): undefined reference to `VP8VFilter8i'
filter_enc.c:(.text.VP8StoreFilterStats+0x294): undefined reference to `VP8SimpleHFilter16i'
filter_enc.c:(.text.VP8StoreFilterStats+0x298): undefined reference to `VP8SimpleVFilter16i'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjasper.a(jas_icc.c.o): In function `jas_icctxt_copy':
jas_icc.c:(.text.jas_icctxt_copy+0xc): undefined reference to `jas_strdup'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjasper.a(jas_icc.c.o): In function `jas_iccprof_createfromclrspc':
jas_icc.c:(.text.jas_iccprof_createfromclrspc+0x84): undefined reference to `jas_iccprofdata_srgblen'
jas_icc.c:(.text.jas_iccprof_createfromclrspc+0x88): undefined reference to `jas_iccprofdata_srgb'
jas_icc.c:(.text.jas_iccprof_createfromclrspc+0x8c): undefined reference to `jas_iccprofdata_sgraylen'
jas_icc.c:(.text.jas_iccprof_createfromclrspc+0x90): undefined reference to `jas_iccprofdata_sgray'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjasper.a(jas_image.c.o): In function `jas_image_addfmt':
jas_image.c:(.text.jas_image_addfmt+0x3c): undefined reference to `jas_strdup'
jas_image.c:(.text.jas_image_addfmt+0x54): undefined reference to `jas_strdup'
jas_image.c:(.text.jas_image_addfmt+0x70): undefined reference to `jas_strdup'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjasper.a(jpc_enc.c.o): In function `jpc_enc_encodemainhdr':
jpc_enc.c:(.text.jpc_enc_encodemainhdr+0x1dc): undefined reference to `jas_strdup'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjasper.a(jas_tvp.c.o): In function `jas_tvparser_create':
jas_tvp.c:(.text.jas_tvparser_create+0x1c): undefined reference to `jas_strdup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
apps/interactive-calibration/CMakeFiles/opencv_interactive-calibration.dir/build.make:265: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_interactive-calibration' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_interactive-calibration] Error 1
make[2]: Target 'apps/interactive-calibration/CMakeFiles/opencv_interactive-calibration.dir/build' not remade because of errors.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6868: recipe for target 'apps/interactive-calibration/CMakeFiles/opencv_interactive-calibration.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [apps/interactive-calibration/CMakeFiles/opencv_interactive-calibration.dir/all] Error 2
[ 99%] Built target opencv_version
make[1]: Target 'all' not remade because of errors.
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: Target 'default_target' not remade because of errors.
```

I know it has to do with the fact that it's not finding the definitions for the functions in `libjpeg-turbo`, `libwebp`, etc., however it seems to be checking the correct path for these (I installed these libraries to the default system directories using the `apt` package manager on Raspbian Jessie)

Here is my CMake configuration as well, if that helps (called from `<opencv-working-directory>/Build/opencv`):

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" \
-D BUILD_DOCS=OFF \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
-D BUILD_TBB=ON \
-D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
-D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
-D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
-D INSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv-working-directory>/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D OPENCV_FORCE_3RDPARTY_BUILD=ON \
-D WITH_CUDA=OFF \
-D WITH_TBB=ON \
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<opencv-working-directory>/Install/opencv \
../../opencv
```

Is there some missing option or dependency I'm missing? Is CMake expecting a certain folder structure to find the required files (mine is not the conventional `mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..`)? Is there a double library linking resolution error somewhere because I also installed the dependencies through `apt`? These are libraries that are necessary for my final program to run, so disabling them is not an option.

I have already tried cross-compiling from Ubuntu 18.04, but that doesn't build all the dependencies and modules that I need. I have also tried running `make` single-threaded since parallel builds often hang the Raspberry Pi's quad-core ARM processor due to race conditions and such.

I also know that this linking structure works on Windows 10 since that's where I tested the code first. (Granted I used MSVC rather than GCC, but that shouldn't make much of a difference since CMake takes care of the cross-platform makefile generation...)

Comment: Apparently, it looks good. But assuming that they have unitest for those applications with the release of new versions, still it could be some incompability....
Other thing you could try, it is to compile the BUILD_opencv_world=ON option.

Comment: Isn't `BUILD_OPENCV_WORLD` for shared libs? I'm trying to avoid shared libraries so that I can keep the program self-contained if possible. I know it'll mean a larger executable but I'd rather have that than have to deal with missing runtime dependencies.

Comment: No, Opencv_World is all the Opencv modules in one library. You can compile it as static or dynamic, but if I am not wrong, it forces to have all the 3rd party dependencies "inside". And I tell this, because it looks like the problems come from the linking with the 3rd party libraries: libwebp, libjarper, libjpeg-turbo.... Also it can happens that the compilation is made with the 3rd party libs in the Opencv repository, and finally you are linking with those default libs in your RP3 OS.